# Why is the interface showing "Interfaces cannot contain fields"?

Tags: c#

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    interface IInterface
    {

    }

    public interface Icar
    {
        int doors;
        string name;
        bool suv
    }

    class Car : Icar
    {
        public int doors;
        public string name;
        public bool suv;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Car s = new Car { doors = 5, name = "my name", suv = true };
            Car t = new Car { doors = 2, name = "my name again", suv = false };

            Console.WriteLine("test");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as the error says, an Interface can not contain `fields`, it can contain `Properties`, so for example, in `Icar` change `int doors`, to `int Doors {get;}`

Comment: The error is *very* clear. Interfaces can only contain properties or methods, not fields.

Comment: @User, well found! :)

Comment: @Hello-World, The accepted answer on the question yours has been closed as a duplicate of was written by Eric Lippert - (you may already be aware of this but,..) he previously worked on the C# compiler at Microsoft, so he **knows his stuff**, his answer is definitely worth a read :) Oddly enough, the question also involves an `ICar` interface!

Answer (score 5):

Because you haven't set your fields as actual properties. Interfaces do not support fields; as the error message states.

Simply change

```
  public int doors;
  public string name;
  public bool suv;
```

To

```
  int doors {get; set;}
  string name {get; set;}
  bool suv {get; set;}
```

Comment: @RyanWilson - you're right; lazy paste on my part. `set` is accepted however.

Comment: Yeah, my bad on the `set` I tested against a class which was `immutable`.

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted.

Comment: @RyanWilson - no worries, wasn't concerned. Little odd, given the answer is correct - hey ho, that's SO for you :)

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if they had to at least give a comment on a way to improve your answer to satisfy their critique. Oh well, since you fixed your answer, I up-voted. At least you're breaking even now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not permitted. As per the [C# reference for interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface):

> An interface can be a member of a namespace or a class and can contain signatures of the following members:
>
> - Methods
> - Properties
> - Indexers
> - Events

The [C# Programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/index) goes into more detail, calling out the things that can't be included in an interface:

> An interface can't contain constants, fields, operators, instance constructors, finalizers, or types. Interface members are automatically public, and they can't include any access modifiers. Members also can't be static.